# JQuery full calendar: eventResize affecting other events

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using JQuery fullCalendar on my project. I'll go directly to my problem.

Whenever I create a new calendar event, and successfully rendered it to the calendar view, then try to resize the newly rendered event, one event keeps resizing also.

so here's my code how I rendered the created event.

this first code is the select event where I get to highlight a range of date and time.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    select: function(start, end){
        if (start.format("YYYY-MM-DD") == end.format("YYYY-MM-DD")) {
            
            $('#createscheduleModal').modal('show'); // opens bootstrap modal to add title
            
            eventData = {
                id: eventCount + 1,
                date : start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                start : start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                end : end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                teacher : auth_id
            }
        }else{
            $('.calendar-view').fullCalendar('unselect');
        }
        eventCount++;
    },
});
```

Then after selecting date ranges, a modal will pop-up so the user can enter a title for the calendar event. in the modal, there is a button with `id="btn-save-sched"`, when the user click the button it saves the calendar event to the database and render it to the calendar. here is the code for this

```
$('#btn-save-sched').click(function(){
    eventData.title = $('#event_name').val(); // add title to eventData object

    if ($('#event_name').val() == "" || $('#event_name').val() == null) {
        swal('Ooops!','Please enter an event name','error');
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            url : teacher_ajax,
            type : 'POST',
            data : eventData,
            success : function(res){
                eventData.editable = true; //set this event to be editable
                $('.calendar-view').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
                $('#event_name').val('');
                $('#createscheduleModal').modal('hide');
            }
        })
    }
});
```

so the code above successfully renders the calendar event into the calendar then when I try to resize this newly created event, another event keeps resizing together with the new event.

Please see the gif below what's happening when I add a new event

[image]

Thanks guys!

Comment: Sounds like the ID is not changing?  Have you checked if `eventCount` is being properly incremented?  Do you have `var eventCount = 0;` somewhere?

Comment: ys I have `var eventCount = 0` at the top of my javascript file.

Comment: ok but if the other events are pre-loaded from the server when the calendar loads, then another event could easily have the same ID. Why not let the server create the ID and send it back to you? Assuming you have a database backing this up, you can guarantee unique IDs across all events then, not just the ones created since this page was last refreshed (which is what you currently have got)